# I can not return the images in the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I extract the images from firebase and put them but I have no success when the function ends.

```
export const saveImages = async (images) => {
    let imgs = [];
    try {
        images.forEach(image => {

            const imgRef = storage.ref(`Works_Realized/Images/${image.name}`).put(image);
            imgRef.on(
                "state_changed",
                snapshot => { },
                err => {
                    console.log(err);
                },
                () => {
                    storage
                        .ref('Works_Realized/Images')
                        .child(image.name)
                        .getDownloadURL()
                        .then(imgUrl => {
                            imgs = [...imgs, { name: image.name, url: imgUrl }];
                            // imgs.push({ name: image.name, url: imgUrl });
                            // console.log(imgs);
                        })
                }
            );

        });
        if (imgs.length > 0) {
            return imgs;
        } else {
            return [];
        }
    } catch (e) {
        Swal.fire('Error', e.message, 'error');
    }
}
```

Please someone help, i have to return an array with de url images.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to stack overflow, the problem in this case is you are using promises to get the downloadUrl, but you are returning the imgs array before that. In this case you could map each image to a promise, and await Promise.all to resolve all of them, giving you the expected array. If you don't understand promises I recommend watching [this short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvYYCGs45L4). Here is the altered code

```js
export const saveImages = async (images) => {
    try {
        const imgs = await images.map(async (image) => {

            const imgRef = storage.ref(`Works_Realized/Images/${image.name}`).put(image);
            imgRef.on(
                "state_changed",
                snapshot => { },
                err => {
                    console.log(err);
                },
                () => {
                    const imgUrl = await storage
                        .ref('Works_Realized/Images')
                        .child(image.name)
                        .getDownloadURL();
                    return { name: image.name, url: imgUrl }

                }
            );

        });
        if (imgs.length > 0) {
            return imgs;
        } else {
            return [];
        }
    } catch (e) {
        Swal.fire('Error', e.message, 'error');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks men, I understand the solution